# `Bad integer for item 1 of list input` when reading a structured datafile in Fortran

Tags: file-io, fortran

I am getting run time error: `Bad integer for item 1 of list input` for the model file, and the error is declared `At line 87 of file teleseis3.f (unit=2,file='model')`

```
* < Default structure >
    tqp=1.0
    tqs=4.0

    nl= 4
    data vp/  5.2, 6.24, 6.58, 7.8, 6*0.0/
    data vs/  3.0, 3.60, 3.80, 4.4, 6*0.0/
    data den/ 2.4, 2.67, 2.80, 3.3, 6*0.0/
    data dep/ 5.5, 9.50, 19.0, 0.0, 6*0.0/

    nl1=4
    data vp1/  5.2, 6.40, 8.0, 7*0.0/
    data vs1/  3.0, 3.75, 4.5, 7*0.0/
    data den1/ 2.4, 2.70, 3.3, 7*0.0/
    data dep1/ 5.0, 30.0, 0.0, 7*0.0/

    nl2=3
    data vp2/   6.40, 8.0, 8*0.0/
    data vs2/   3.75, 4.4, 8*0.0/
    data den2/  2.70, 3.3, 8*0.0/
    data dep2/ 30.00, 0.0, 8*0.0/

 c ------------ End initialization ----------------------------
  read(*,*) model
  if(model(1:4) .ne. 'none') then
c    print*, model
     open(2,file=model)
         READ(2,'(a40)') name
         READ(2,*) TQP,TQS,NL ,(VP (L),VS (L),DEN (L),DEP (L),L=1,NL )
c   line 87 is here
         READ(2,*)         NL1,(VP1(L),VS1(L),DEN1(L),DEP1(L),L=1,NL1) 
         READ(2,*)         NL2,(VP2(L),VS2(L),DEN2(L),DEP2(L),L=1,NL2)
     close(2)
      endif
```

The data in the 'model' file arranged in lines to break 'default structure' pattern.

```
#model
1.0 4.0 50 5.8 3.2 2.6 15.0
5.8 3.2 2.6 0.0 
6.8 3.9 2.9 9.4
8.1 4.5 3.4 0.0
8.10119 4.48486 3.37906 15.6
8.08907 4.47715 3.37688 20
8.07688 4.46953 3.37471 20
8.0554   4.45643 3.37091 35
8.0337   4.44361 3.3671 35
8.0118  4.43108 3.3633 35
7.9897  4.41885 3.3595 35
8.55896 4.64391 3.43578 0
8.64552 4.6754 3.46264 45
8.73209 4.7069 3.48951 45
8.81867 4.7384 3.51639 45
8.90522 4.76989 3.54325 45
9.13397 4.93259 3.72378 0
9.64588 5.22428 3.8498 50
9.90185 5.37014 3.91282 50
10.1578 5.51602 3.97584 50
10.212  5.54311 3.984    35
10.2662 5.5702 3.99214 35
10.7513 5.94508 4.38071 0
10.91   6.09418 4.41241 51
11.0656      6.24046    4.44317 50
11.2449 6.31091 4.50372 100
11.4156 6.37813 4.56307 100
11.5783 6.44232 4.62129 100
11.7336 6.5037         4.67844  100
11.8821 6.5625      4.7346  100
12.0245 6.6189         4.78983  100
12.1613 6.67317 4.84422 100
12.2932 6.72548 4.89783 100
12.4207 6.77606 4.95073 100
12.5447 6.82512 5.00299 100
12.6655 6.87289 5.05469 100
12.7839 6.91957 5.1059        100
12.9004 6.96538 5.15669 100
13.0158 7.01053 5.20713 100
13.1306 7.05525 5.25729 100
13.2453 7.09976 5.30724 100
13.3607 7.14423 5.35706 100
13.4774 7.18892 5.40681 100
13.596         7.23403  5.45657 100
13.6804 7.26597 5.49145 100
13.6875 7.26575 5.50642 100
13.7117 7.26486 5.55641 100
13.7166 7.26466 5.56645 100
4 5.8 3.2 2.6 15.0
  5.8 3.2 2.6 0.0 
  6.8 3.9 2.9 9.4
  8.1 4.5 3.4 0.0
3 5.8000 3.2000 2.6000 10.000
  6.8000 3.9000 2.9000 22.000
  8.1000 4.5000 3.3800 0.0000
```

However the error appears. Please give me ways to correct it.

Here I provide a testing script named'test.f':
Please test it for me because I still has the error.

```
     PARAMETER (ND0=2048,NM0=6,LK0=10,NL0=48,PI=3.141593,RAD=.0174533)
      IMPLICIT COMPLEX*8 (Z)
      CHARACTER NAME*40,NAM*4, prefix*80, adel*3, outfile*80
      COMMON /STR0/NL ,VP (NL0),VS (NL0),DEN (NL0),DEP (NL0)
      COMMON /STR1/NL1,VP1(NL0),VS1(NL0),DEN1(NL0),DEP1(NL0)
      COMMON /STR2/NL2,VP2(NL0),VS2(NL0),DEN2(NL0),DEP2(NL0)


     read(*,'(a80)') model
      if(model(1:4) .ne. 'none') then
c    print*, model
     open(2,file=model)
         READ(2,'(a40)') name
         READ(2,*) TQP,TQS,NL ,(VP (L),VS (L),DEN (L),DEP (L),L=1,NL )
         READ(2,*)         NL1,(VP1(L),VS1(L),DEN1(L),DEP1(L),L=1,NL1)
         print *,NL1,VP1(L),VS1(L),DEN1(L),DEP1(L)
         READ(2,*)         NL2,(VP2(L),VS2(L),DEN2(L),DEP2(L),L=1,NL2)
     close(2)
      endif
```

Comment: the problem is in the input file. The 50 on the first line indicates there should be 50 sets of four values, but there are only  48.

Comment: Oh,I noticed,but that's not the problem,the line where '50' lies in  should  alsobe counted ,so I changed it to 49,but the same error stil exists.@agentp

Comment: On the line `READ(2,*) TQP,TQS,NL ,(VP (L),VS (L),DEN (L),DEP (L),L=1,NL )` you read *and* use `NL`. This is a probable cause of error. Can you set `NL` in advance instead?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, reading and using `NL` in this way is not a problem: the value of `NL` is appropriately defined before it is required in the list item the implied loop.  This is a correct and useful idiom.

Comment: Thanks @francescalus I wasn't aware this was safe.

Comment: If you want the gory details, @PierredeBuyl, then F2008 9.6.4.5.1 has many.

Comment: I counted the first line in the 48. One thing you can do is temporarily insert a line before 87 to read a couple of reals and print it out to see where you are.

Comment: It would be useful to create a shortened example, which fits here completely and which we can try to run with your data and more easily find the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: Yes,I have added a short code for testing in my question,please test it for me,thanks.

Comment: you need to print the result of the last read `VP (NL),VS (NL),DEN (NL),DEP (NL)` *before* the line resulting in the error. You will see you are reading into the next block of data because the files claims there are fifty sets of values when there are really forty eight.